# Is there an alternative to Ubuntu 20.04 which does by itself avoid the overheating issues of Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, overheating, distro-recommendation

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04 I got a <strike>drastic</strike> (*) increase in heat generation. That much that the fans run non-stop when, for example, writing here.

I've seen some suggestions for solutions in:

- [Ubuntu 20.04 LTS overheating after upgrading from Ubuntu 19](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241065/ubuntu-20-04-lts-overheating-after-upgrading-from-ubuntu-19)
- [Overheating problem Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243147/overheating-problem-ubuntu-20-04)
- [Ubuntu 20.04 - Shutdown after Overheating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232813/ubuntu-20-04-shutdown-after-overheating)
- [Overheating ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233758/overheating-ubuntu-20-04)

but they are generally too complicated for me.

So I am wondering which alternative I have to going back to Ubuntu 18.04? Is it possible that one of the other Ubuntu flavors has better heat management?

(*) EDIT: the temperature increase is about 10 degree C. Thus it's not necessarily drastic, however, in my particular case, it was the difference between quiet + moderately warm (45-65 C - Ubuntu 18.04) and noisy + noticeably warm/hot (55-75 C - Ubuntu 20.04) during office work and a bit video media via the browser.

EDIT: some more info regarding the system

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep VGA -A1
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 [8086:5917] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. UHD Graphics 620 [19e5:3e04]
```

```
$ sudo lshw | grep -i cpu
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
          slot: CPU0
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
```

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          8
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-7
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              4
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           142
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Stepping:                        10
CPU MHz:                         900.019
CPU max MHz:                     4000,0000
CPU min MHz:                     400,0000
BogoMIPS:                        3999.93
Virtualization:                  VT-x
L1d cache:                       128 KiB
L1i cache:                       128 KiB
L2 cache:                        1 MiB
L3 cache:                        8 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-7
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
Vulnerability L1tf:              Mitigation; PTE Inversion; VMX conditional cache flushes, SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Mds:               Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Mitigation; PTI
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Full generic retpoline, IBPB conditional, IBRS_FW, STIBP conditional, RSB filling
Vulnerability Srbds:             Mitigation; Microcode
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx p
                                 dpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 mo
                                 nitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c 
                                 rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_a
                                 d fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm
                                  ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d
```

```
$ sudo dmidecode | grep -A 9 "System Information"
System Information
    Manufacturer: HUAWEI
    Product Name: MACH-WX9
    Version: M14
    Serial Number:
    UUID:
    Wake-up Type: Other
    SKU Number: C128
    Family: MateBook X
```

Ubuntu **20.04**: A couple of minutes browsing and a bit on youtube:

```
$ sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp --interval 10
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ PkgTmp  PkgWatt
1.81    1831    33947   61  2.03
2.27    1603    61104   61  2.29
1.41    1707    25399   61  1.62
1.85    1605    37852   60  1.74
3.79    1946    30286   61  2.27
14.90   2565    90107   65  7.46
10.14   1660    83041   62  4.08
6.05    1693    20996   61  2.54
7.27    2296    56579   61  4.01
3.90    1651    35907   61  2.18
2.05    1189    4312    61  1.21
1.94    1178    3641    60  1.17
2.15    1193    8310    60  1.25
9.23    2368    71835   77  4.64
10.50   2345    100792  62  5.64
11.16   2301    103861  63  5.91
9.30    2056    87392   62  4.69
12.90   2458    101382  63  6.68
5.99    2456    85671   62  4.08
6.94    2583    84243   63  4.73
8.66    2602    70112   74  5.37
4.01    1634    82126   63  2.76
5.79    1916    69195   63  3.35
2.07    1440    46764   61  1.88
2.37    1849    19398   61  1.85
15.30   2763    103252  63  8.45
6.85    1619    91617   63  3.25
22.83   2673    113022  65  10.83
18.23   1953    80293   65  6.47
15.13   1833    18368   67  5.16
16.66   1937    31341   66  5.71
15.45   1841    19264   67  5.13
15.39   1883    25636   67  5.26
15.15   1841    18823   67  4.99
18.36   2194    38167   78  6.89
18.59   3148    25048   74  12.38
16.54   2872    20575   71  9.90
16.52   2827    19098   70  9.81
17.12   2737    25913   71  9.97
16.69   2597    20014   73  9.48
17.00   2530    19476   73  9.33
17.31   2483    20659   78  9.22
17.12   2515    19317   78  9.40
17.17   2492    19405   71  9.31
14.33   2440    28754   70  7.60
17.29   2475    100814  72  8.03
17.20   1717    88112   69  5.67
13.84   1454    21107   68  3.85
21.12   2390    95464   78  9.27
17.46   1958    83714   69  6.50
13.65   1621    17670   68  4.24
14.03   1677    31452   68  4.42
18.87   2151    63174   75  7.21
16.51   1760    108382  69  5.62
15.55   1736    93805   71  5.30
18.16   2097    106745  70  7.24
14.60   1759    103832  68  5.60
15.83   1826    38515   68  5.43
```

Ubuntu **18.04**: A couple of minutes from idle to browsing and a bit on youtube + gather.town:

```
$ sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp --interval 10
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ PkgTmp  PkgWatt
2.82    1768    46529   38  2.08
10.25   2147    60467   39  3.99
8.15    2114    75586   39  3.43
15.51   2082    89943   44  5.26
28.77   2033    135634  42  7.45
35.45   1387    119133  45  6.43
26.16   921 49050   42  4.57
20.72   841 27382   42  3.57
20.35   833 25787   41  3.52
20.99   840 25759   42  3.56
15.63   1490    65972   45  3.98
25.14   1867    138887  44  6.55
28.08   1272    75522   43  5.43
33.81   1484    89905   46  6.35
49.25   2158    212435  50  10.21
33.23   2167    142528  51  8.17
42.19   1965    147226  51  8.96
21.10   2083    112678  49  6.20
13.71   1535    71116   48  3.66
33.95   1441    115981  49  7.23
2.58    1272    11592   47  1.32
29.64   1331    75626   50  6.23
17.86   1094    25192   50  5.28
19.97   1168    43827   51  5.47
17.47   1786    35032   51  6.51
17.30   2052    24559   51  7.21
16.25   1824    23812   51  6.49
16.59   1405    23990   53  5.54
16.21   1642    24421   52  5.90
16.49   1556    24731   52  5.79
17.98   1739    35984   54  6.31
16.95   1723    26705   56  6.15
18.94   1782    34843   57  6.48
19.36   1647    37899   55  6.31
27.01   1701    69851   55  7.91
5.92    1410    55265   53  2.94
14.67   1683    94236   53  5.14
15.48   1982    96783   54  5.31
13.70   1799    104173  54  5.06
34.00   1584    191978  57  8.42
42.97   1597    144692  57  9.59
46.40   1364    146367  58  9.50
45.37   1195    145161  59  9.17
46.29   1111    152743  58  9.09
29.85   1344    169345  56  5.91
21.98   1397    134286  57  5.44
19.80   1454    120425  56  5.35
13.62   1320    113002  55  3.77
15.14   1292    115582  54  3.98
14.41   1283    113753  54  3.84
19.52   1135    116535  55  4.62
19.16   1378    123416  54  5.15
19.04   1438    117835  53  5.19
29.28   1566    191343  55  7.87
32.23   1315    150525  57  7.74
24.89   1511    178689  54  6.57
39.11   1435    126184  57  8.63
25.95   1438    87309   60  6.13
52.46   1569    157048  57  9.61
21.06   1876    43350   59  7.38
20.24   1834    52450   57  6.87
19.74   1549    40736   57  6.07
19.90   1854    43349   58  6.87
20.04   1448    43349   56  5.79
18.89   1658    46643   56  6.08
20.72   1136    44509   55  5.10
20.91   1615    56817   57  6.16
19.08   1682    44514   56  6.21
20.33   1480    46851   56  5.88
19.24   1878    44820   56  6.81
19.05   1620    46734   55  5.96
18.87   1719    46084   57  6.22
18.77   1589    43724   57  5.84
18.80   1646    46136   56  5.98
18.05   1654    44568   57  5.90
19.51   1495    43831   56  5.69
20.10   1425    47115   56  5.58
34.38   1278    107277  59  7.71
37.71   1461    150771  59  9.29
```

I now tried Ubuntu MATE **20.04** too (from idle to youtube+gather.town, a video thing):

```
sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,GFXWatt --interval 10
[sudo] password for eris: 
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ PkgTmp  PkgWatt GFXWatt
0.52    1375    1665    46  0.63    0.00
0.81    1695    2413    46  0.75    0.00
3.06    2447    13288   47  1.79    0.00
16.00   3177    172104  51  9.36    0.00
25.35   3291    185541  72  14.66   0.00
18.26   3182    160839  55  10.76   0.00
17.86   3012    116988  65  9.22    0.00
23.82   3025    112455  68  12.28   0.00
23.10   2357    126068  67  8.70    0.00
19.91   1799    185705  60  5.62    0.00
23.89   2786    161790  70  10.65   0.00
28.50   3336    151280  73  15.69   0.00
27.92   3314    138395  74  15.58   0.00
32.25   3111    145045  72  15.35   0.00
19.68   2126    66127   67  7.43    0.00
18.63   2113    37507   66  6.93    0.00
19.86   2183    52183   67  7.69    0.00
19.08   2060    40849   69  6.96    0.00
19.01   2046    36192   69  6.86    0.00
20.27   2151    50647   71  7.52    0.00
31.72   3188    141914  76  15.35   0.00
```

Comment: Have you tried to update the system to latest supported kernel and driver versions ? Run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` ? If there are errors in a new version, they will be fixed at one point, earlier or later. Also if you have graphics or other drivers from third part (not from Ubuntu repos or added PPA's) you should check for updated versions there.

Comment: We need more information. There are at least 2, maybe more, main sources of overheating, the processor and/or the GPU. Do you know yours? For processor, we need to know CPU make and model.

Comment: The main issue here is that I don't really know how to perform proper diagnostics and implement some custom cpu voltage controls for example. That said, @SorenA, yes, the system is updated and upgraded, and it's fresh, so the only ppa's I added are from my failed attempts to stop the system from running on full force while writing a text.
@DougSmythies so I can try to put together all the information I know how to get, but maybe you could give a couple more hints on what would actually help, for example, what is the `CPU make`?

Comment: when it comes to temperatures, I can't see if either the CPU or the GPU leads, both of them are generally on a high level.

Comment: For an Intel i7-8550U, I would run this command in some terminal window all the time: `sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp --interval 10` and thus always be aware of the processor package temperature. I am a server person and can not help with GPU heat issues.

Comment: Charging seems to also be a problem, temperature rises by a couple degrees just by plugging it in.

Comment: `turbostat` seems to be unavailable for 20.04? `E: Unable to locate package turbostat`

Comment: I'll try to update the bios now, it currently has trouble charging against the battery drain with a fast charger... and that while the system is mostly idle.

Comment: I think `turbostat` might be part of the `linux-tools-common` package.

Comment: This is by no means a proper answer, because the underlying causes are not clear at this point, but you could try to run a less resource intensive distribution (e.g. Lubuntu/Xubuntu/Bodhi) on your device. Just by typing "MateBook X overheating" into a search machine I got the impression that it is a common problem with this device and that it can generally run a little hot.

Comment: But seeing that you also have charging problems it seems that this might not really be worthwhile. I did find this repo in which someone using Debian (not Ubuntu, but because Ubuntu is based on Debian it might be worth to look at nonetheless) describes his setup process for a Matebook X 2017 (including a little about power management https://github.com/lidel/linux-on-huawei-matebook-x-2017

Comment: To me, this looks like a kernel bug report. A release-upgrade should not cause a "*drastic increase in heat generation*" nor cause fans to go wild.

Comment: So I'm completely blind fishing here, that said, I've read someone suggesting keeping a Windows on a Matebook to handle the bios updates etc, and I did have a Windows on a partition before I upgraded Ubuntu, which I removed in the process to have the whole disk for Ubuntu. Maybe some drivers were provided by Windows while I was using 18.04 on the other partition (windows was preinstalled and I left it there and forgot the login credentials).
I will try to update the Bios, for example with the link providet by @Fynn or this one https://gist.github.com/derjohn/2c19554415cea09830225314c2072807

Comment: well I tried to follow the instructions in gist.github.com/derjohn/2c19554415cea09830225314c2072807 and got a `Specified firmware is older than installed '0.1.36 < 0.1.40'` response (although I thought I saw 0.1.18 being installed). So in summary, I learned that I'm not qualified to play around on this level of the system.

Comment: Turbostat data looks O.K. Kind of high temperature during low load, so suspect main heat source might be something else, like GPU, but not sure.

Comment: Just as a test, try disabling turbo CPU frequencies: `echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo`. I do not know if this works for your system, but try adding graphics watts to your turbostat list of stuff to show, `GFXWatt`, so `sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,GFXWatt --interval 10`

Comment: I installed 18.04 again to have some actual measurements from that (added it to the main question). Well and the difference is not *drastic*, its about 10 degree C which just happened to be the range where the notebook starts making noise and being a bit too warm for comfort.
With the comment from @Fynn that Matebooks may have heat issues anyway, the answer might just be that 20.04 needs a bit more resources and the Matebook handles that poorly.
I'll try Xubuntu/Lubuntu 20.04 (and Budgie to see if its same as Ubuntu, since it looks nice)
I'll also think about rephrasing the question.

Comment: I consider the idle difference of 23 degrees pretty drastic.

Comment: @DougSmythies well not pretty to say the least. Also, I now tried Ubuntu MATE 20.04 giving similar results to Ubuntu 20.04, which might not be too surprising since they are both Ubuntu based, but I thought that maybe Mate manages better since it is less fancy compared to Ubuntu. But no, barely different.
So again, I don't know how this can be, its way beyond what I know. Maybe the bios I use (and failed to upgrade) was supported by 18.04 by chance and is not anymore in 20.04 (since it is outdated)... or maybe not...

Comment: It doesn't appear to be processor related, but I am not certain. My next guess would be GPU (Graphics), about which I know nothing. Which kernel versions were used in these tests? I am thinking of [this](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=207245).

Comment: For Mate 20.04 it is `Kernel: Linux 5.8.0-50-generic` so that would fit. For Ubuntu 18.04 I'm not sure, I've seen that it supports kernels up to 5.3 (or 5.4?) but I don't know if that is what it was shipped with when I installed it.

Comment: I now tried Elementary OS 5.1 (`Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-73-generic`) and then I thought maybe even newer kernels work, and installed Ubuntu 21.04 (`Kernel: Linux 5.11.0-17-generic`). Both had the same issues as before (if kernels > 5.2 have the issue no surprise) however, on 21.04 I found `NVIDIA X Server Settings` which allowed me to select an "Intel low energy mode" (can't look up the exact name - the thing did break since then) but the system works for me now. This solves the usability issue with newer Ubuntu versions for me; it does not, however, really tell the story of what the issue was.